¿Cómo configurar el tema oscuro en Material con Angular 18 para que cambie el fondo a oscuro?
Muy buenas compañeros!!
Estoy intentando implementar la seleccion de tema claro y tema oscuro con material en proyectos de Angular 18.
El caso es que llevo varias pruebas y no doy con ello al 100% ya que consigo cambiar muchos de los valores de mis paletas custom pero no el del fondo de la página, que se queda siempre en blanco.
Estos son mis archivos:
1- En el angular.json tengo esto declarado
 "styles": [
  "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/rose-red.css",
  "src/styles.scss"
 ],

2- Mi archivo de estilos style.scss es este:
  /* ********************** */
 /* USES AND IMPORTS FILES */
/* ********************** */
@use '@angular/material' as mat;




  /* ************************ */
 /* TYPOGRAPHY CONFIGURATION */
/* ************************ */


  /***********************************/
 /* FONTS IMPORTS AND CONFIGURATION */
/***********************************/
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@300;400;500&display=swap');
     
$fontConfig: (
  display-4: mat.m2-define-typography-level(112px, 112px, 500, 'Work Sans', -0.0134em),
  display-3: mat.m2-define-typography-level(56px, 56px, 500, 'Work Sans', -0.0089em),
  display-2: mat.m2-define-typography-level(45px, 48px, 400, 'Work Sans', 0.0000em),
  display-1: mat.m2-define-typography-level(34px, 40px, 400, 'Work Sans', 0.0074em),
  headline: mat.m2-define-typography-level(24px, 32px, 400, 'Work Sans', 0.0000em),
  title: mat.m2-define-typography-level(20px, 32px, 500, 'Work Sans', 0.0075em),
  subheading-2: mat.m2-define-typography-level(16px, 28px, 400, 'Work Sans', 0.0094em),
  subheading-1: mat.m2-define-typography-level(15px, 24px, 500, 'Work Sans', 0.0067em),
  body-2: mat.m2-define-typography-level(14px, 24px, 500, 'Work Sans', 0.0179em),
  body-1: mat.m2-define-typography-level(14px, 20px, 400, 'Work Sans', 0.0179em),
  button: mat.m2-define-typography-level(14px, 14px, 500, 'Work Sans', 0.0893em),
  caption: mat.m2-define-typography-level(12px, 20px, 400, 'Work Sans', 0.0333em),
  input: mat.m2-define-typography-level(inherit, 1.125, 400, 'Work Sans', 1.5px)
);

  /********************/
 /* LIGHT THEME TEXT */
/********************/
$dark-text: #000000;
$dark-primary-text: rgba($dark-text, 0.87);
$dark-accent-text: rgba($dark-primary-text, 0.54);
$dark-disabled-text: rgba($dark-primary-text, 0.38);
$dark-dividers: rgba($dark-primary-text, 0.12);
$dark-focused: rgba($dark-primary-text, 0.12);

$light-theme-foreground: (
  base:              black,
  divider:           $dark-dividers,
  dividers:          $dark-dividers,
  disabled:          $dark-disabled-text,
  disabled-button:   rgba($dark-text, 0.26),
  disabled-text:     $dark-disabled-text,
  elevation:         black,
  secondary-text:    $dark-accent-text,
  hint-text:         $dark-disabled-text,
  accent-text:       $dark-accent-text,
  icon:              $dark-accent-text,
  icons:             $dark-accent-text,
  text:              $dark-primary-text,
  slider-min:        $dark-primary-text,
  slider-off:        rgba($dark-text, 0.26),
  slider-off-active: $dark-disabled-text,
);

  /*******************/
 /* DARK THEME TEXT */
/*******************/
$light-text: #ffffff;
$light-primary-text: $light-text;
$light-accent-text: rgba($light-primary-text, 0.7);
$light-disabled-text: rgba($light-primary-text, 0.5);
$light-dividers: rgba($light-primary-text, 0.12);
$light-focused: rgba($light-primary-text, 0.12);

$dark-theme-foreground: (
  base:              $light-text,
  divider:           $light-dividers,
  dividers:          $light-dividers,
  disabled:          $light-disabled-text,
  disabled-button:   rgba($light-text, 0.3),
  disabled-text:     $light-disabled-text,
  elevation:         black,
  hint-text:         $light-disabled-text,
  secondary-text:    $light-accent-text,
  accent-text:       $light-accent-text,
  icon:              $light-text,
  icons:             $light-text,
  text:              $light-text,
  slider-min:        $light-text,
  slider-off:        rgba($light-text, 0.3),
  slider-off-active: rgba($light-text, 0.3),
);




  /* ************************ */
 /* BACKGROUND CONFIGURATION */
/* ************************ */


  /**************************/
 /* LIGHT THEME BACKGROUND */
/**************************/
$light-background:    #fafafa;
$light-bg-darker-5:   darken($light-background, 5%);
$light-bg-darker-10:  darken($light-background, 10%);
$light-bg-darker-20:  darken($light-background, 20%);
$light-bg-darker-30:  darken($light-background, 30%);
$light-bg-lighter-5:  lighten($light-background, 5%);
$dark-bg-tooltip:     lighten(#2c2c2c, 20%);
$dark-bg-alpha-4:     rgba(#2c2c2c, 0.04);
$dark-bg-alpha-12:    rgba(#2c2c2c, 0.12);

$light-theme-background: (
  background:               $light-background,
  status-bar:               $light-bg-darker-20,
  app-bar:                  $light-bg-darker-5,
  hover:                    $dark-bg-alpha-4,
  card:                     $light-bg-lighter-5,
  dialog:                   $light-bg-lighter-5,
  tooltip:                  $dark-bg-tooltip,
  disabled-button:          $dark-bg-alpha-12,
  raised-button:            $light-bg-lighter-5,
  focused-button:           $dark-focused,
  selected-button:          $light-bg-darker-20,
  selected-disabled-button: $light-bg-darker-30,
  disabled-button-toggle:   $light-bg-darker-10,
  unselected-chip:          $light-bg-darker-10,
  disabled-list-option:     $light-bg-darker-10,
);

  /*************************/
 /* DARK THEME BACKGROUND */
/*************************/
$dark-background:     #313131;
$dark-bg-lighter-5:   lighten($dark-background, 5%);
$dark-bg-lighter-10:  lighten($dark-background, 10%);
$dark-bg-lighter-20:  lighten($dark-background, 20%);
$dark-bg-lighter-30:  lighten($dark-background, 30%);
$light-bg-alpha-4:    rgba(#fafafa, 0.04);
$light-bg-alpha-12:   rgba(#fafafa, 0.12);

$dark-theme-background: (
  background:               $dark-background,
  status-bar:               $dark-bg-lighter-20,
  app-bar:                  $dark-bg-lighter-5,
  hover:                    $light-bg-alpha-4,
  card:                     $dark-bg-lighter-5,
  dialog:                   $dark-bg-lighter-5,
  tooltip:                  $dark-bg-lighter-20,
  disabled-button:          $light-bg-alpha-12,
  raised-button:            $dark-bg-lighter-5,
  focused-button:           $light-focused,
  selected-button:          $dark-bg-lighter-20,
  selected-disabled-button: $dark-bg-lighter-30,
  disabled-button-toggle:   $dark-bg-lighter-10,
  unselected-chip:          $dark-bg-lighter-20,
  disabled-list-option:     $dark-bg-lighter-10,
);




  /* ********************** */
 /* PALETTES CONFIGURATION */
/* ********************** */


  /*****************/
 /* LIGHT PALETTE */
/*****************/

  /***********/
 /* PRIMARY */
/***********/
$light-primary-palette: (
  main: #808000,
  lighter: #d9d9b3,
  darker: #636300,
  200: #808000,
  contrast : (
    main: $dark-primary-text,
    lighter: $light-primary-text,
    darker: $dark-primary-text,
  )
);

$light-primary-theme: mat.m2-define-palette($light-primary-palette, main, lighter, darker);

  /**********/
 /* ACCENT */
/**********/
$light-accent-palette: (
  main: #c8c800,
  lighter: #efefb3,
  darker: #b4b400,
  200: #c8c800,
  contrast : (
    main: $dark-primary-text,
    lighter: $light-primary-text,
    darker: $dark-primary-text,
  )
);

$light-accent-theme: mat.m2-define-palette($light-accent-palette, main, lighter, darker);

  /********/
 /* WARN */
/********/
$light-warn-palette: (
  main: #ff7300,
  lighter: #ffd5b3,
  darker: #ff5600,
  200: #ff7300,
  contrast : (
    main: $dark-primary-text,
    lighter: $light-primary-text,
    darker: $dark-primary-text,
  )
);

$light-warn-theme: mat.m2-define-palette($light-warn-palette, main, lighter, darker);

  /*****************/
 /* DARK PALETTE */
/*****************/

  /***********/
 /* PRIMARY */
/***********/
$dark-primary-palette: (
  main: #808000,
  lighter: #d9d9b3,
  darker: #636300,
  200: #808000,
  contrast : (
    main: $light-primary-text,
    lighter: $dark-primary-text,
    darker: $light-primary-text,
  )
);

$dark-primary-theme: mat.m2-define-palette($dark-primary-palette, main, lighter, darker);

  /**********/
 /* ACCENT */
/**********/
$dark-accent-palette: (
  main: #c8c800,
  lighter: #efefb3,
  darker: #b4b400,
  200: #c8c800,
  contrast : (
    main: $light-primary-text,
    lighter: $dark-primary-text,
    darker: $light-primary-text,
  )
);

$dark-accent-theme: mat.m2-define-palette($dark-accent-palette, main, lighter, darker);

  /********/
 /* WARN */
/********/
$dark-warn-palette: (
  main: #ff7300,
  lighter: #ffd5b3,
  darker: #ff5600,
  200: #ff7300,
  contrast : (
    main: $light-primary-text,
    lighter: $dark-primary-text,
    darker: $light-primary-text,
  )
);

$dark-warn-theme: mat.m2-define-palette($dark-warn-palette, main, lighter, darker);




  /* ********************************** */
 /* LIGHT AND DARK THEME CONFIGURATION */
/* ********************************** */


  /**************************/
 /* LIGHT THEME DEFINITION */
/**************************/
$light-theme: mat.m2-define-light-theme((
    color: (
        primary: $light-primary-theme,
        accent: $light-accent-theme,
        warn: $light-warn-theme,

    ),
    typography: $fontConfig,
    foreground: $light-theme-foreground,
    background: $light-theme-background,
));

  /*************************/
 /* DARK THEME DEFINITION */
/*************************/
$dark-theme: mat.m2-define-dark-theme((
    color: (
        primary: $dark-primary-theme,
        accent: $dark-accent-theme,
        warn: $dark-warn-theme,
    ),
    typography: $fontConfig,
    foreground: $dark-theme-foreground,
    background: $dark-theme-background,
));




  /* ********************* */
 /* ASSIGN THEME BY CLASS */
/* ********************* */


  /******************************/
 /* LIGHT AND DARK ASSIGNATION */
/******************************/
body {
    &.theme-light {
        @include mat.all-component-themes($light-theme);
    }

    &.theme-dark {
        @include mat.all-component-themes($dark-theme);
    }
}

3- La vista del componente es esta:
<button mat-raised-button (click)="toggleTheme()">Toggle Theme</button>


<br>
<br>
<section>
    <div class="example-label">Primary</div>
    <div class="example-button-row">
        <button mat-button color="primary">Primary</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-button color="accent">Accent</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-button color="warn">Warn</button>
        &nbsp;
        <a mat-button target="_blank">Link</a>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-button disabled color="primary">Primary disabled</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-button disabled color="accent">Accent disabled</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-button disabled color="warn">Warn disabled</button>
        &nbsp;
        <a mat-button target="_blank" disabled>Link disabled</a>
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</section>
<br>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>

<br>
<br>
<section>
    <div class="example-label">Raised</div>
    <div class="example-button-row">
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Primary</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-raised-button color="accent">Accent</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-raised-button color="warn">Warn</button>
        &nbsp;
        <a mat-raised-button target="_blank">Link</a>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-raised-button disabled color="primary">Primary disabled</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-raised-button disabled color="accent">Accent disabled</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-raised-button disabled color="warn">Warn disabled</button>
        &nbsp;
        <a mat-raised-button target="_blank" disabled>Link disabled</a>
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</section>
<br>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>

<br>
<br>
<section>
    <div class="example-label">Stroked</div>
    <div class="example-button-row">
        <button mat-stroked-button color="primary">Primary</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-stroked-button color="accent">Accent</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-stroked-button color="warn">Warn</button>
        &nbsp;
        <a mat-stroked-button target="_blank">Link</a>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-stroked-button disabled color="primary">Primary disabled</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-stroked-button disabled color="accent">Accent disabled</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-stroked-button disabled color="warn">Warn disabled</button>
        &nbsp;
        <a mat-stroked-button target="_blank" disabled>Link disabled</a>
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</section>
<br>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>

<br>
<br>
<section>
    <div class="example-label">Flat</div>
    <div class="example-button-row">
        <button mat-flat-button color="primary">Primary</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-flat-button color="accent">Accent</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-flat-button color="warn">Warn</button>
        &nbsp;
        <a mat-flat-button target="_blank">Link</a>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-flat-button disabled color="primary">Primary disabled</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-flat-button disabled color="accent">Accent disabled</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-flat-button disabled color="warn">Warn disabled</button>
        &nbsp;
        <a mat-flat-button target="_blank" disabled>Link disabled</a>
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</section>
<br>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>

<br>
<br>
<section>
    <div class="example-label">Icon</div>
    <div class="example-button-row">
        <div class="example-flex-container">
            <button mat-icon-button color="primary">
                <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            <button mat-icon-button color="accent">
                <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            <button mat-icon-button color="warn">
                <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            <button mat-icon-button color="primary">
                <mat-icon>open_in_new</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            <button mat-icon-button color="accent">
                <mat-icon>open_in_new</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            <button mat-icon-button color="warn">
                <mat-icon>open_in_new</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            <button mat-icon-button color="primary" disabled>
                <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            <button mat-icon-button color="accent" disabled>
                <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            <button mat-icon-button color="warn" disabled>
                <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            <button mat-icon-button color="primary" disabled>
                <mat-icon>open_in_new</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            <button mat-icon-button color="accent" disabled>
                <mat-icon>open_in_new</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            <button mat-icon-button color="warn" disabled>
                <mat-icon>open_in_new</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<br>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>

<br>
<br>
<section>
    <div class="example-label">FAB</div>
    <div class="example-button-row">
        <div class="example-flex-container">
            <button mat-fab color="primary">
                <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            <button mat-fab color="accent">
                <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            <button mat-fab color="warn">
                <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            <button mat-fab color="primary">
                <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            <button mat-fab color="accent">
                <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            <button mat-fab color="warn">
                <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            <button mat-fab color="primary" disabled>
                <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            <button mat-fab color="accent" disabled>
                <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            <button mat-fab color="warn" disabled>
                <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            <button mat-fab color="primary" disabled>
                <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            <button mat-fab color="accent" disabled>
                <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            <button mat-fab color="warn" disabled>
                <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<br>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>

<br>
<br>
<section>
    <div class="example-label">Mini FAB</div>
    <div class="example-button-row">
        <button mat-mini-fab color="primary">
            <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-mini-fab color="accent">
            <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-mini-fab color="warn">
            <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-mini-fab color="primary">
            <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
        </button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-mini-fab color="accent">
            <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
        </button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-mini-fab color="warn">
            <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
        </button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" disabled>
            <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-mini-fab color="accent" disabled>
            <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-mini-fab color="warn" disabled>
            <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" disabled>
            <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
        </button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-mini-fab color="accent" disabled>
            <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
        </button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-mini-fab color="warn" disabled>
            <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </div>
</section>
<br>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>

<br>
<br>
<section>
    <div class="example-label">Extended Fab</div>
    <div class="example-button-row">
        <button mat-fab extended color="primary">
            <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
            Primary
        </button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-fab extended color="accent" >
            <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
            Favorite
        </button>
        &nbsp;
        <a mat-fab extended color="warn">
            <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
            Link
        </a>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-fab extended color="primary" disabled>
            <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
            Primary
        </button>
        &nbsp;
        <button mat-fab extended color="accent" disabled>
            <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
            Favorite
        </button>
        &nbsp;
        <a mat-fab extended color="warn" disabled>
            <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
            Link
        </a>
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</section>
<br>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
  
<br>
<br>
<form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field color="primary">
        <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi">
    </mat-form-field>
    &nbsp;
    <mat-form-field color="accent">
        <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi">
    </mat-form-field>
    &nbsp;
    <mat-form-field color="warn">
        <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi">
    </mat-form-field>
    &nbsp;
    <mat-form-field color="primary">
        <mat-label>Leave a comment</mat-label>
        <textarea matInput placeholder="Ex. It makes me feel..."></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
    &nbsp;
    <mat-form-field color="accent">
        <mat-label>Leave a comment</mat-label>
        <textarea matInput placeholder="Ex. It makes me feel..."></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
    &nbsp;
    <mat-form-field color="warn">
        <mat-label>Leave a comment</mat-label>
        <textarea matInput placeholder="Ex. It makes me feel..."></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
    &nbsp;
</form>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>

4- La lógica del componente es esta:
import { Component, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-componenteprueba',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatButtonModule, MatDividerModule, MatIconModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule],
  templateUrl: './componenteprueba.component.html',
  styleUrl: './componenteprueba.component.scss'
})
export class ComponentepruebaComponent {
    
    isDarkTheme: boolean = false;

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {

    }

    toggleTheme() {
      this.isDarkTheme = !this.isDarkTheme;
      if (this.isDarkTheme) {
        this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, 'theme-light');
        this.renderer.addClass(document.body, 'theme-dark');
      } else {
        this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, 'theme-dark');
        this.renderer.addClass(document.body, 'theme-light');
      }
    }
}

El fondo de los botones y los textos se cambian correctamente, pero el fondo de la página y el color de los textos 'example-label' no cambian al pulsar el botón de cambiar de tema.
Os pongo unas capturas de lo que hace el codigo en el navegador:
Tema claro:

Tema oscuro:

¿Hay algo que no esté implementando bien?
Gracias a todos y todas de antemano!!

Acabo de dar con ello.... tan simple como añadir la clase: 'mat-app-background' al body en el archivo index.html:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Prueba Material 3</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="mat-typography mat-app-background">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>

